# How to convert php number_format() function to python

Tags: php, python

I want to convert php code to python3.

this is my php code

```
echo "<td class='text-left'>".number_format($amount,2)."</td>";
```

I want to convert this php into Python. Please help me in that

Comment: Try reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp) about `number_format` in PHP and then [here](https://pyformat.info/) for the `format` method in python. Specificly go to the section `Padding Numbers`.

Comment: Where, I am new to python learning now. can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: You can click the links in my comment and try to understand how to use the `format` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import locale


def number_format(num, places=0):
    return locale.format_string("%.*f", (places, num), True)
```

**Using:**

```
print(number_format(12345.6789, 2))
```

**Result:**

12345.68

[More info](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57563/locale.format_string)